# Less: mixins styles vs added style rules

Tags: css, less, mixins

I have mixins for red button

e.g.

```
.btnRed{
     background:red;
     color:white;
     border-radius:3px;
     min-width:200px;
     font-size:18px;
 }
```

I use it to style my main buttons , but for one I overwrite min-width and font-size:

```
.class1{
     .btnRed;
     min-width:0;
     font-size:25px;
}
```

When I check it in firebug I get this result:

```
.class1{
     background:red;
     color:white;
     border-radius:3px;
     min-width:200px;
     font-size:18px
} 
.class1{
     min-width:0;
     font-size:25px;
 }
```

and added styles are ignored.

So my question is:

how can I combine mixins and new added styles in one class1 and make added styles important without declaring !important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your LESS and all seems to be fine.

When applying `class1` on elements I've got the overridden values.

See this [working example](http://jsbin.com/godez/2/edit).

So my guess would be that your problem lies somewhere else

Comment: Yup, Thanks!! I didn't pay attention that my .btnRed has `&:link,&:active` states in it. I did like this `.class1{.btnRed; 
&:link,&:active{new styles}}`